# instance block accessing instance variable before object creation

Tags: java, instance, block

I have a doubt regarding instance block and constructors. I have learnt that the instance block is always executed before the constructor.

However if I try to access an instance variable, or even try to use 'this', there is no kind of error.
But then how can I access an instance variable, even before it's object is created.

Comment: Question is based on a false premiss.

Comment: I would suggest you to read - [`JLS - Section# 12.5`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) and [`JLS - Section # 15.9`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) completely, without skipping a word.

Comment: The reading @RohitJain recommends is not trivial, but well worth the effort.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan.. Yeah, not everything is important there. But may be OP can feel the importance with my wordings, and then have a good read. He will understand the behind-the-process scene.

Answer (score 2):

> I have learnt that the instance block is always executed before the constructor.

Then you have learnt wrong. They aren't. They are executed *during* the constructor, after the implicit super() call.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor does not actually create the object, so the paradox you indicate does not actually exist. The constructor only runs on a previously allocated object.

However, the `new` operator that is used to call the constructor performs both the task of creating the object and then calling the constructor on it, in one atomic operation.

Also, the Java compiler implements instance blocks by effectively adding the code contained in them to each constructor, so they, also, run as part of the constructor being called.

Answer (score -1):

Because, at the beginning of an object's life, the Java virtual machine (JVM) allocates enough memory on the heap to accommodate the object's instance variables. When that memory is first allocated, however, the data it contains is unpredictable. If the memory were used as is, the behavior of the object would also be unpredictable. To guard against such a scenario, Java makes certain that memory is initialized, at least to predictable default values, before it is used by any code.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.